# Python не работает код не могу найти ошибку

Tags: python, переменные, ввод

Вот такой код:

```
import re

class Interpreter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file_name = filename
        self.variables = {}
        with open(filename) as code:
            self.lines = len(code.readlines())
        self.current_line = 1

    def split_code(self, input_str):
        pattern = r'\w+|\.|\=|<.*?>|\"w+"'
        result = re.findall(pattern, input_str)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            try:
                result[i] = int(result[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return result

    def lex(self, c):
        if c == []:
            self.current_line += 1

        elif c[0] == "out":
            text = ""
            for n in range(len(c)-1):
                t = c[n]
                if t[0:2] == "__":

                    try:
                        text += ''.join(self.variables[t[2:]])
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f"Ошибка. Перменная {t[2:]} отсутствует!")
                else:
                    text += t
                n += 1
                text += ""
            print(text)

        elif c[0] == "new":
            if c[1] in self.variables:
                del self.variables[c[1]]

            if c[1] == "int":
                if c[4] == "inp":
                    zn = int(input(" ".join(c[5:])))
                else:
                    zn = int(c[4])
                self.variables[c[2]] = zn
            elif c[1] == "string":
                if c[4] == "inp":
                    zn = input(" ".join(c[5:]))
                else:
                    zn = c[4]
                self.variables[c[2]] = zn


    def run(self):
        with open(self.file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as code:
            while self.current_line <= self.lines:
                line = code.readline().replace("\n", "")
                codeline = self.split_code(line)
                self.lex(codeline)
                self.current_line += 1




inter = Interpreter("programm.txt")
inter.run()
```

Код текстового файла:

```
new int x = inp Введи число

new string line = inp Вводи текст быстра

out __x __line
```

На вывод программа должна подавать, то что вводится в `x` и `line`

Comment: Добавьте везде по коду отладочную печать. А лучше логирование. Если кто-то будет с вашим кодом разбираться, ему придётся тоже это делать.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт, user586450, вот полезная ссылка как задать вопрос на SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (ознакомьтесь, получите ответ в разы быстрей)

Comment: text += str(self.variables[t[2:]])

Comment: @СергейШ не помогло

Comment: @CrazyElf, сделал. Но теперь такая ошибка выходит: https://imgur.com/qYZqNMZ
Не понимаю, что с ней делать

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

class Interpreter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file_name = filename
        self.variables = {}
        with open(filename) as code:
            self.txt_list = code.readlines()
        self.lines = len(self.txt_list)
        self.current_line = 1

    def split_code(self, input_str):
        ...

    def lex(self, c):
        if not c:
            self.current_line += 1

        elif c[0] == "out":
            text = ""
            for t in c[1:]:
                if t[0:2] == "__":

                    try:
                        text += str(self.variables[t[2:]])
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f"Ошибка. Перменная {t[2:]} отсутствует!")
            print(text)

        ...

    def run(self):
       for code in self.txt_list:
            line = code.replace("\n", "")
            codeline = self.split_code(line)
            self.lex(codeline)
            self.current_line += 1

inter = Interpreter("programm.txt")
inter.run()

# веди число333
# води текст быстраddd
# 333ddd
```

Comment: Не работает и ничего не выводит вообще

Comment: Или что то не так сделал: